# Adding Google glass' cordova plugin without using Node JS

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins, google-gdk

I am working on researching things for app development with `Google Glass`. It is very well understood that in Native environment - the app development is straight forward. (using GDK - glass dev kit)
Coming to development with `Cordova`, there are cordova plugins made for Glass and are hosted on `Github` - check the links here -

1. [Glass core Link](https://github.com/aphex/cordova-glass-core)
2. [Glass Touch Link](https://github.com/aphex/cordova-glass-touch)
3. [Glass Gesture Link](https://github.com/aphex/cordova-glass-gesture)

Well, what I understand now is, these plugins can be added to my app using Node JS command line. There are few restrictions and I cannot install Node JS in my environment. Is there a way to add these plugins to my app without using Node? My `Cordova` version is 2.7.0.

How to add the .java files manually? and where should I add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it's awfully fiddly but you can do it.

Steps to follow are:

1. Clone the repository - `git clone https://github.com/aphex/cordova-glass-core.git`
2. Copy the JavaScript file into your www folder (usually contained in a directory called 'js' or something, within 'www').
3. Make sure your JavaScript file is referenced in your HTML file, in order to call the native code.
4. Add the Java files to the mapping package (in this instance, com.rossgerbasi.cordova.glass)
5. Alter config.xml to call these (look in plugin.xml - you can hopefully decode this to figure out which settings you require.

Plugman (which is the Cordova plugin handler) interrogates `plugin.xml` to automate the process for copying and pasting config.xml/AndroidManifest.xml settings and files to the correct location without manual intervention - so there is no reason why it cannot be done manually. It's just a bit fiddly.

Decoding the plugin.xml file as follows (using: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification as a reference):

```
<plugin xmlns="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/plugins/1.0"
        id="com.rossgerbasi.cordova.glass.core"
        version="0.0.2">

    <name>GlassCore</name>

    <keywords>cordova,google glass,glass,android</keywords>

    <description>
        Plugin to add Google Glass Support to your Cordova Application. Additional JS plugin allows developer to get voice prompt speech to text results.
    </description>

    <license>MIT</license>

    <author>Ross Gerbasi</author>

    <engines>
        <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.0"/>
    </engines>

    <js-module src="www/cordova-glass-core.js" name="GlassCore">
        <clobbers target="com.rossgerbasi.cordova.glass.core"/>
    </js-module>

    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/widget">
            <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
            <feature name="GlassCore">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.rossgerbasi.cordova.glass.GlassCorePlugin"/>
                <param name="onload" value="true"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
            <activity
                    android:name="com.rossgerbasi.cordova.glass.GoogleGlassActivity"
                    android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
                    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                    android:noHistory="true"
                    android:theme="@style/GlassTheme">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data
                        android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                        android:resource="@xml/app_launch_voice_trigger"/>
            </activity>
        </config-file>

        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.glass" android:required="true"/>
        </config-file>

        <source-file
                src="res/xml/app_launch_voice_trigger.xml" target-dir="res/xml"/>

        <source-file
                src="res/values/styles.xml" target-dir="res/values"/>

        <source-file
                src="res/values/glass.xml" target-dir="res/values"/>                

        <source-file src="src/com/rossgerbasi/cordova/glass/GoogleGlassActivity.java"
                     target-dir="src/com/rossgerbasi/cordova/glass"/>
        <source-file src="src/com/rossgerbasi/cordova/glass/GlassCorePlugin.java"
                     target-dir="src/com/rossgerbasi/cordova/glass"/>
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

The main tag is `plugin` - which is fine. `name`, `keywords`, `description`, etc. are just bits of metadata used by plugins.cordova.io should you host it there (I personally don't so skip these).

`engines` details the minimum cordova requirements for the plugin. This tells us at least Cordova 3.x which but it should be fine anyway.

`js-module` is used by the Cordova engine to setup an automatic JavaScript reference under com.rossgerbasi.cordova.glass.core.GlassCore - which you can then access in your JavaScript.

`platform name="android"` is the part of `plugin.xml` which Cordova uses to set up the plugin for the Android environment - in Cordova 3.x, you add your platforms to one centralised project and so this is needed by the CLI to know what to do if the Android platform is "installed" (i.e. added to your Cordova 3.x project). In your instance, you are using Cordova 2.x for Android - so this is still relevant for us. N.b. when you move to Cordova 3.x, then you can define all your platforms using this tag, such as `platform name="ios"` to handle the iOS Xcode setup.

Looking side the `platform` tag:
`config-file` is used to contain text you want pasted into config.xml - since config.xml contains mappings between your JavaScript and native code, this has to match. I could write an entire paragraph on this tag alone, but I'd recommend looking at other plugins to understand how they work. The `target` attribute tells the CLI which file to copy this to - it points to `res/xml/config.xml` which is where the Android's config.xml file is - so open this up and study it to understand it. You can copy the tags (`preference` and `feature` from plugin.xml to here).

There's a second `config-file` which, this time, points to AndroidManifest.xml with the `target` being AndroidManifest.xml (i.e. the one in the root of the Eclipse project). You will also see there's a `/manifest/application` tag which points to the tree structure within AndroidManifest.xml - so you will find a `manifest` tag, and an `application` tag within this - and you can copy all of the `activity` tag into here.

There is a *third* `config-file` tag - this has a `parent` attribute of `"/manifest"` so, as you can imagine, the text contained within here will go in the `manifest` tag of AndroidManifest.xml - and reside here. This third `config-file` tag details permissions that the class package requires from the Android system, in order to execute.

Next there are five `source-file` tags. `src` tells you where you can find the the source file in the local directory, relative to `plugin.xml`, so the first instance you can find `app_launch_voice_trigger.xml` in res/xml/ and it's meant to be pasted to /res/xml/ in the Eclipse project directory (i.e. where your project's `project.xml` file was from the `config-file` tag above).

Then there's the two Java files which detail the package structure. In src, there should be a `com/` folder, within this a `rossgerbasi/` folder, then `cordova`, then `glass` and the GlassCorePlugin.java will reside in here.

Once you have added all these, then open Eclipse (if it isn't open already) right-click on your project and 'Refresh' and go! You should hopefully then be able to interact with the plugin.

Comment: No worries - I forgot to add point (6) - make sure all other options in plugin.xml are then added to your project. Under the `<platform name="android">` tag, you will find them all here. Namely, it alters the config.xml, AndroidManifest.xml and it adds three other xml files in.

Comment: But decoding it should be relatively straight forward anyway ;)

Comment: where should I add this plugin.xml? under res/xml of the project?

Comment: You don't add plugin.xml anywhere - the 3.x CLI decodes plugin.xml and copies all the information inside. Let me edit my original answer to give a bit more information.

Comment: the prob here is - I cannot use PG 3.x also. 
I am using only PG 2.7.0 (manually setup because of my network restrictions to add/install NODE JS)

Comment: OK I've edited - and that's fine - 3.x CLI uses plugin.xml to automate the plugin-add process. So what I am saying, is we can decode plugin.xml to find out what it is doing, and mimic that.

My edited answer breaks down the plugin.xml file - I hope that makes more sense now.

Comment: I.e. 2.7.0 will suffice since we are manually performing the steps described in plugin.xml which is used by 3.x and above.

Comment: awesomeness of an explanation is here @keldar... I am doing it the right way... just checking with ur edited answer... I think I am growing :D

Comment: Ha - hope it helps! If so, don't forget to select it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: I accepted the answer @keldar.. It worked for me. 
Coming into the details, I was able to port the app on to the google glass device.

Comment: @keldar.. can you guide me understanding the cordova-glass-core.js in the zip file downloaded from GITHUB please? or kindly let me know whether I can get any online instructions/tutorial to understand things.